# Can I use elliptic curve cryptography as a password with Bouncy Castle in C#?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I'd like to encrypt some data on a server so if someone got access to the database and codebase the secret data would not be compromised.

It seems to me a good way to do this is through elliptic curve cryptography.

I'm wondering how to do this in [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)? I've Googled around and read some blog posts, but they generate keys unrelated to strings and I'm not sure how to implement it with a password, plus I don't want to make a mistake.

essentially I'd like something like this:

```
var privateKey = GetPrivateKey("secretpassword");
var publicKey = GetPublicKey(privateKey);


string data = "secret data";
var encryptedData = encryptData(publicKey, data);
string data2 = unencryptData(privateKey, data);

Assert.AreEqual(data, data2);
```

This is my current work in progress:

```
    string password = "n55xSMb7J7n7K8zBRn"; // this will not be hardcoded in the application. It will come from a password prompt
    byte[] salt = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + password);
    int iterations = 5;
    int keySizeInBits = 32;
    Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator(new Sha256Digest());
    generator.Init(PbeParametersGenerator.Pkcs5PasswordToUtf8Bytes(password.ToCharArray()), salt, iterations);
    KeyParameter key = (KeyParameter)generator.GenerateDerivedMacParameters(keySizeInBits);
    byte[] k = key.GetKey();


    X9ECParameters ecP = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Sec.SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
    ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N, ecP.H, ecP.GetSeed());
    IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator g = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
    g.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, new SecureRandom(k)));
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair aKeyPair = g.GenerateKeyPair();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateK = aKeyPair.Private;
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicK = aKeyPair.Public;
```

Comment: Why passwords? Can't you just use proper random keys? And obviously you can't keep the private key on the server for this to be secure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to run a process where I type in the password to access the data. I guess using something like LastPass it doesn't matter what the private key is... Agreed about not keeping the privateKey on the server.

Comment: In that case I'd still create a random ECC key, but encrypt is with password based encryption. This involves a proper password hash like scrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Do you need the case when everyone can encrypt the data and only you can decrypt it as an owner of the private key? If not, why you are going to use asymmetric cryptography here? AFAIK, its main purpose is to create digital signatures for data. While it is possible with elliptic curve cryptography, symmetric algorithms are better suited for encryption/decryption tasks.

Comment: @DenPakizh only I need access to it. It is my understanding if someone compromises the database and codebase they will be able to decrypt the data with a symmetric algorithm whereas with asymmetric they will not. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: They will be able to decrypt the data only in case when they own your secret key. That is true for both symmetric and asymmetric algorithms.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith: You need to figure out _where_ to store your keys.  Asymmetric encryption will only help if you need different people to be able to encrypt but not decrypt.  You need to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: @SLaks I plan on storing the public key in the C# code in the application and the password to generate the private key in my head and or in LastPass. Thanks for the link to Lippert's article. That doesn't change what I want to do. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: So you will enter the password every time the application starts? That will work, but you aren't getting any good out of asymmetry since you have the private key anyway.

Comment: I plan on entering the password when I use the encrypted data, which may be a few times per week. It will be a max of once per day.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith: Since you decided to use asymmetric cryptography, you must follow the only way to use it properly. So in case of Elliptic Curve Cryptography, you should pick one of the recommended curve and other parameters then generate random key-pair. After that you will be able to store your private key in password protected file using PKCS#8 or encrypt it by yourself.